# angular not recognizing styles.scss and therefore angular-notifier is not working

Tags: css, angular

I have question about angular and i'm very new to it. After imported the [angular-notifier library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier)  i successfully got it to work. But when the notification is displayed, somehow the styles aren't working and it's in plain text. I imported the needed styles in the styles.scss Basically the notification should pop up when i click a button. Due to styles not working the message will drop on the bottom under the footer.

I hope u can help me fix this problem :).

My **styles.scss**:

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
@import "~angular-notifier/styles";
```

My **angular.json** file:

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"angular": {
"projectType": "application",
"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
"style": "scss"
}
},
"root": "",
"sourceRoot": "src",
"prefix": "app",
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
"outputPath": "dist/angular",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"aot": true,
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
"styles": [],
"scripts": []
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"fileReplacements": [
{
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
],
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"extractCss": true,
"namedChunks": false,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "2mb",
"maximumError": "5mb"
},
{
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
"maximumWarning": "6kb",
"maximumError": "10kb"
}
]
}
}
},
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "angular:build"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"browserTarget": "angular:build:production"
}
}
},
"extract-i18n": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "angular:build"
}
},
"test": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
"options": {
"main": "src/test.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
"karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
"styles": [],
"scripts": []
}
},
"lint": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
"options": {
"tsConfig": [
"tsconfig.app.json",
"tsconfig.spec.json",
"e2e/tsconfig.json"
],
"exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
}
},
"e2e": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
"options": {
"protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
"devServerTarget": "angular:serve"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"devServerTarget": "angular:serve:production"
}
}
}
}
}
},
"defaultProject": "angular"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put   `"src/styles.scss"` inside `styles` array in `angular.json`

```
"styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
```